# Manually Creating an OData feed in Asp.Net Core, Using feed in Power BI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-core, powerbi

I am trying to manually write a Web Api that will serve as an OData feed. I don't need much functionality, just the ability to export data stored within Entity framework to an application such as Power BI. I only need to be able to view, so I was planning on just implementing GET requests.

I currently have a standard web api that returns back properly formatted JSON, but I am having trouble formatting this into something that I can import into Power BI as an OData Feed.

Here's a gist of what I have.

```
public class Report
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    ...
}


[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpGet("GetReports/{userID}")]
    public IEnumerable<Report> GetReportsByUser(string userID)
    {
        return GetAllReportsByUser(userID); 
    }
    ...
}
```

I need something like this to work (obviously won't in the current form)
[image: Enter OData Feed URL]

Comment: Have you looked at this? [Create an OData v4 Endpoint Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

Comment: Yes, I have. The reason this does not work is "Install the OData Packages" section. The platform we are on, 1.0.0-rc1-update2 (coreclr), doesn't support any OData Packages, so that is why I need to do the formatting manually.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ASP.NET Core 1 (aka ASP.NET 5), use the [OData vNext package](https://www.myget.org/gallery/odatavnext) to build your OData service. There is a [sample service](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/tree/v6.0.0-alpha1/vNext/samples/ODataSample.Web) on Github.

Comment: Already tried it. It requires some of the other packages to be rc2, not rc1. I am required to stay on rc1.